# How to set maxZoom for interpolate after 18 with BING layer

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to "zoom in" (by interpolation if not possible more tham 18)...

```
var BING_KEY = 'AuhiCJHlGzhg93IqUH_oCpl_-ZUrIE6SPftlyGYUvr9Amx5nzA-WqGcPquyFZl4L'

var map = L.map('map').setView([1.2862100, 103.8541900], 18)
map.options.maxZoom = 20;  // NOT WORKING
map.options.maxNativeZoom = 18;  // NOT WORKING

var bingLayer = L.tileLayer.bing(BING_KEY).addTo(map)
```

It is not working (blank image), after 18 (clicking "+")

See  [Leaflet-JS BING-layer](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-bing-layer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [options available for a `L.Map`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-option) are different from the [options available for a `L.TileLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tilelayer-option). Note how both `Map` and `TileLayer` both have a `maxZoom` option with different meaning, and how `TileLayer` inherits the `maxNativeZoom` option from the `GridLayer` class.

Therefore, apply the options to the `TileLayer` and not to the `Map`:

```
var map = L.map('map');
var bingLayer = L.tileLayer.bing({bingKey: 'ABCD', maxNativeZoom: 18, maxZoom: 20}).addTo(map);
```